# PHP - mktime() function returning wrong time

Tags: php

### The Problematic Code

I am trying to build a time using some string values extracted from a file.
This is basically the code that runs.

```
$hour = "18";            
$minutes = "0";
$month = "28";
$day = "4";
$year = "2016";
echo("<div>"."Current PHP version: " . phpversion()."</div>");  
echo("<div>hour :: ".(int)$hour."</div>");  
echo("<div>minutes :: ".(int)$minutes."</div>");        
echo("<div>month :: ".(int)$month."</div>");        
echo("<div>day :: ".(int)$day."</div>");        
echo("<div>year :: ".(int)$year."</div>");                  
$built_time = mktime((int)$hour,(int)$minutes,0,(int)$month,(int)$day,(int)$year);
echo("<div>  Built Time [Y-m-d H:i:s]: ".date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s',$built_time)."</div>");
```

---

### The Wrong Results

The output is receive for this is:

[image: Output for given code snippet]

Several more attempts yielded the following results

[image: Other attempts]

As you can see sometimes it does provide the correct result! Why does this happen. It cannot be a timezone issue since its giving dates which are years into the future.

As per [mktime() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) the parameter sequence is also correct. Wonder why this call is failing.

Comment: `$month=28` ~ I think that might be a few too many

Comment: I don't think a 28th month exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is correct **according to your inputs.**

`mktime` accetps `month` value to be between 1-12. In each of your attempts except last one month values are `28,28,21,21.`

So when the value of month is more then 12, it references the appropriate month in the following year(s). So in your first two case it would be `04` and and in 3rd and 4th it would be `09`.

> When you pass value of month greater then 12 it calculates the N months after current month. So in first two cases it's **April 2018(04)** and and in 3rd and 4th it's **September(09) 2017**.

So the outputs are correct according to your inputs.

Comment: Ah silly me, The input values ive been getting are quite unpredictable!

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly the right output. 28th month of 2016 is April 2018

Answer (score 1):

It was likely just a simple mistake but there are not 28months to a year so I guess the month and day were swapped.

```
$hour = "18";            
$minutes = "0";
$month = "4";
$day = "28";
$year = "2016";
$built_time = mktime((int)$hour,(int)$minutes,0,(int)$month,(int)$day,(int)$year);

echo"
<div>"."Current PHP version: " . phpversion()."</div>
<div>hour :: {$hour}</div>
<div>minutes :: {$minutes}</div>
<div>month :: {$month}</div>
<div>day :: {$day}</div>
<div>year :: {$year}</div>
<div>  Built Time [Y-m-d H:i:s]: ".date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s',$built_time)."</div>";
/*
outputs

Current PHP version: 5.3.2
hour :: 18
minutes :: 0
month :: 4
day :: 28
year :: 2016
Built Time [Y-m-d H:i:s]: 2016-04-28 18:00:00

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$built_time=strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day." ".$hour.":".$minutes.":00");
   echo("<div>  Built Time [Y-m-d H:i:s]: ".date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s',$built_time)."</div>");
```